# What are the differences among bugs, issues and tasks in TFS

Tags: tfs, workitem

Could anyone give me a short explanation on the differences among bugs, issues, and tasks in TFS?

Comment: It would help to know which template you are using.  For example: "Bug" has subtle differences between templates.  Some templates use work items differently.

Comment: I'd suggest you accept an answer or edit your question or comment on answers on what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 52):

## For the [Scrum TFS Process Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731587(v=vs.110).aspx)

- [Bug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731589%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)- Any problem in existing functionality, or missing functionality. Defect in code or requirement, error which is not designed to be.
- [Issue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731580%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Impediment)- Any problem which might block the development process, example : a third party driver you identified as dependency is not releasing on time, so it is an issue in your development process.
- [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731574%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)- Any work which is planned as part of development of your project, either as result of bug, or issue or requirements, including requirement analysis or development, or testing. etc.

## For the [Agile TFS Process Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380647(v=vs.110).aspx)

- [Bug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380645(v=vs.110).aspx)- A bug communicates that a potential problem exists in the code that your team is developing.
- [Issue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380654(v=vs.110).aspx)- An event or cause that may delay shipping.
- [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380700(v=vs.110).aspx)- A task communicates the need to do some work. Each team member can define tasks to represent the work that they need to accomplish.

Comment: These would apply only to a Scrum process, I believe.

Answer (score 11):

When we used TFS in the past.

**ISSUE** - Is a problem reported by a user of the software that requires investigation. This could be a code bug or a requirement change (prior to it been made a change request)

**BUG** - Is a problem "in the code" confirmed by a developer. Information can be provided like  possible causes and workarounds. Can be marked as fixed and link to source code check ins.

**TASK** - Is a work item that is given to people to complete. Such as a feature that needs to be completed. If it is a programming task, it can be linked to source code check ins.

**Update**

See comment below. Just remember, use the system in a way that benefits your team. Everyone works differently.

**ISSUE** - Covers everything about the project which may require some work or investigation. It is not necessarily an issue with the code, but it creates a stating point for investigation. If an issue is raised, which requires a change to the project it may lead to a bug or task.

Comment: Would this be the standard way to use issues, bugs and tasks given the Agile methodology in TFS?

Comment: No didibus.  Jon's definitions are incorrect.  Issue is an outside dependency for development - third party library, IT needing to stand up a server environment etc - and has nothing to do with the code under development.  A bug is how you would label a code problem regardless if you're running Scrum or just Agile.  A code bug that is reported by a user has a status of "New".  Once it's confirmed, the status of the bug changes to "Confirmed".  A requirement change on the other hand is entered as a User Story.

Comment: @Joshua. 4 years on and working in different agile teams not just as a developer. I would agree, An issue covers everything, and could later link to a bug or a task if it is code related. It could however be raised as an infrastructural concern, i.e. update from .Net 4 to .Net 4.5 runtime.

Answer (score 3):

MSF Agile Work Item Types

MSF Agile contains the following work item types:

- Bug. Represents a problem or potential problem in your application.
- Risk. Represents a possible event or condition that would have a negative impact on your  project.
- Scenario. Represents a single path of user interaction through the system.
- Task. Represents the need for a member of the team to do some work.
- Quality of Service Requirement. Represents a requirement constraining how the system should work.

MSF CMMI Work Item Types

MSF CMMI contains the following work item types:

- Bug. Represents a problem or potential problem in your application.
- Change Request. Represents a proposed change to your application.
- Issue. Represents a situation that may block work or is currently blocking work.
- Requirement. Represents a description of what your application should do to solve a customer problem.
- Review. Represents the results of a code, design, or deployment review.
- Risk. Represents a possible event or condition that would have a negative impact on the project.
- Task. Represents the need for a member of the team to do some work.

Please refer the links here which describes the details of Work Item Types:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400752.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668962.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes **Error, Bug and defect** is defined as
A mistake in the code is called Error when it is identified by the testing team called a defect, and when it is accepted by the development team called Bug. If it does not meet with customer requirements as in the SRS document it is called Failure.